# How to create Web Service for uploading image to Azure Storage Blob?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, web-services, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload an image that I get from my Android device as a ByteArray

to my Azure Storage Blob. By using a webservice in asp.net.

But I can't figure out how to do this...

Here is my code so far:

```
[WebMethod]

    public string UploadFile(byte[] f, string fileName)
    {

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        // Retrieve a reference to a container. 
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

        // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        container.SetPermissions(
         new BlobContainerPermissions
         {
             PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
         });


        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "filename...".
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        // Create or overwrite the "filename..." blob with contents from a local file.
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("C:\\filepath"))
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
        }

        return "OK";
    }
```

This code gets the image from a local file path on my computer, and thats not what I want.

I want to use the byte[] array 'f' wich I recive from my Android device instead of 'C:\filepath'

How can I do that ?

Comment: Where have you used the `byte[] f`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I did miss the last statement! YOu need to write the byte array to the stream, something like `using (FileStream f = File.Open(@"C:\Test.txt"))
            {
                f.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            }`

Comment: I've done it like this:

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(f, writable: false))
            {
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);
            }

Dose this seem correct ?

Comment: I dont have access to Azure right now, so cannot give a working code. But I think that the code you showed should work. Did you try it out?